# Invalid Syntax: ImportError,e in Django core

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make migrations for my Django project, it was working and building fine before I installed and implemented the Django registration-redux module.

These are the errors I currently get and I don't understand why or how to fix it.

```
 File "/Users/user/Documents/django-projects/tango_with_django_project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/django-projects/tango_with_django_project/manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 54
    except ImportError,e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: What version of Python do you think you're using? `except ImportError,e` isn't valid in Python 3, but it was in Python 2. These days you need to write `except ImportError as e`.

Comment: I am running Django version 3.2.5 and Python version 3.9.5

Comment: You have an older version of Django installed. It's not verison 3.2.5, but somewhere around version 1.4 – before Django supported python 3. It says that the code is in `/opt/homebrew/lib/`, so I guess this older version was installed with Homebrew at some point, and this import path is found before where you have the current version of Django. I suggest using some kind of virtual environment to isolate your Django project.

Comment: @DeclanMorgan: you have installed Django-1.4, you should work with your package manager to upgrade the Django-version.

Comment: @HåkenLid Thanks that helped, didn't realize that there was an older version installed that would cause difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback talks about a line with `except ImportError,e:` as content. If we look at Django's GitHub repository, this is the case for [django-1.4](/questions/tagged/django-1.4). Indeed, on [GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/core/management/__init__.py#L54) we see for [django-1.4](/questions/tagged/django-1.4):

> ```
>     except ImportError,e:
> ```

whereas [django-1.3](/questions/tagged/django-1.3) [[GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.3.x/django/core/management/__init__.py#L54) and [django-1.5](/questions/tagged/django-1.5) [[GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/core/management/__init__.py#L54) mention different content.

This thus means that you run a Python application written for [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) with [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), but these two are not compatible with each other: code written for [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) is not compatible with [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) and vice versa.

You thus should upgrade your Django version. This means that if you use a package manager like `pip3` (or use it as package manager of a virtual environment), you upgrade Django with:

```
pip3 install --upgrade Django
```

Comment: Thanks Willem, upgrading the older version of Django installed helped resolve the issue.